# XSL 1.0 number-format function round w/ no decimal

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm attempting to convert a number value w/ 2 decimal places to a string with no decimal places. I read about format-number, and I thought this function was achieving my desired result, but in testing w/ the value 1.00 I was getting a 2 back.  I read about some rounding issues in other threads, but all those had results that included decimals which I need mine not to and instead round to the nearest whole number.  Please see my example below, and thank you so much in advance for your help.

<xsl:value-of select='format-number((1.00), "#")'/>

result = 2

I need the result to show 1.  This seems so simple, but I'm obviously not understanding.

Comment: Your requirement *"to convert a number value w/ 2 decimal places to a string with no decimal places"* is confusing. The value `1.00` is not a number, it is a string. Converting the string to a number using `number('1.00')` returns the number `1`. If you want, you can convert the result back to string, but I don't see what purpose that would serve. In any case, it's not clear whether you actually need to do any rounding, or just strip trailing zeros.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: format-number(1.00, '#') should not return 2. It's a little bit difficult to determine exactly what it should return in XSLT 1.0, because the specification refers to the documentation for JDK 1.1.8 which is no longer readily available (and in any case it was woefully under-specified) but I think if you're getting 2 then that's a bug, and you need to chase it up with the specific XSLT processor vendor.

Comment: I deleted the uff-8 tag which is totally inappropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First , `format-number((1.00), "#"` does NOT return `2` in any XSLT processor I know of.

More importantly, you should not use `format-number` to round numbers - esp. not in XSLT 1.0 where different processors can return different results. If you want to round a number to the nearest integer, use the provided [round()](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-round) function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="round('1.00')"/>
```

returns `1`.

If you only need to strip trailing zeros, then you can simply convert the input value to a number:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number('1.00')"/>
```

returns `1`.

Comment: I appreciate your input.  The value of 1.00 came from a different system, and I could not get hold of this raw data in Middleware to confirm it was a 1.00.  All I could see was the XML output showing a 2 and the IDoc in the other system showing a 1.00 in the field we were bringing in on the XSL.  I now believe they must be sending a 2.00 even though, in their system I see a 1.00.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: IIUC you are not able to view the input to the XSL transformation directly - but you should be able to get it by applying a stylesheet using only the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) template.